# Pass uploaded file as a parameter to javascript method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am passing the uploaded file as a parameter in the JavaScript method. Then Firebug is throwing error like `SyntaxError: illegal character`.

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="employerLogoUpload" />

<a id="_fileUploadLink" href="#" onClick="javascript:ajaxFileUpload(" +document.getElementById('fileUpload').value+ ");">Upload</a>
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ajaxFileUpload(val){
   ...
}

$(document).ready(function(){

   $('a#_fileUploadLink').on('click', function(){

       var val = $('#fileUpload').val();  

       ajaxFileUpload(val);

   });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use inline event attributes change your `onclick` handler to look like this:

```
onClick="ajaxFileUpload(document.getElementById('fileUpload').value);"
```

That will, on click, call the `ajaxFileUpload()` function and pass it the current value of the `fileUpload` element.

The way you had it your onclick looked like this:

```
onClick="javascript:ajaxFileUpload("
```

...and the `+document.getElementById('fileUpload').value+ ");"` after that was *not* part of the onclick - the attribute ends with its closing quotation mark. (Also you don't need the `javascript:` part inside any inline event handler.)

But since you've tagged the question with jQuery you could lose the inline code and put the following in a script block after the elements and/or in a document ready handler:

```
$("#_fileUploadLink").click(function(e) {
    ajaxFileUpload($("#fileUpload").val());
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The `.preventDefault()` is there to stop the browser moving to the top of the document when you click the link.